# Microsoft Graph: verify with which secret an access token was obtained

Tags: azure, oauth, jwt, access-token, azure-ad-graph-api

When getting an access token for Microsoft Graph using the client_credentials method (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/auth-v2-service) you use a client secret.

Is there any way one can verify which secret (the secrets have IDs) was used to obtain the access token? Alternatively, is there any way to assign roles/ permissions to only on specific secret? Or, as another alternative, can you get ID tokens using a client secret?

I am sorry, but I can not find this information in Microsoft's documentation nor the internet.

Comment: Right now your question include multiple questions. Can you please break them into separate questions?

Comment: All questions are referring to the same goal: identify the secret used to obtain the token. Therfore, I will not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way one can verfiy which secret (the secrets have IDs)
> was used to obtain the access token?

No.

> Alternatively, is there any way to assign roles/ permissions to only
> on specific secret?

No. They are assigned on the service principal.

> Or, as another alternative, can you get ID tokens using a client
> secret?

Only if a user is involved, not through client credential flow.

Comment: Thank you. In this case, do you know what is the the best practice to assure that an access token belongs to my app and not some random user who is using my app?

Comment: To get a token as a user, a _scope_ is needed. If there is no _scp_ claim in the token, it means it was acquired by an application by itself. You can also define an appRole/application permission on your API app registration. These can only be used by an application through a client secret or certificate. You can also check the _appidacr_ (v1.0) or _azpacr_ (v2.0) to verify that they have the value 1 or 2 (client secret or client certificate used). Access token reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#claims-in-access-tokens